# Angular 12 Unit Testing: Directive with Can't bind to 'scrollIntoForm'

Tags: angular-directive, directive, angular12

I have a scroll-into-new-form.directive.ts file

```
import {
  Directive,
  ElementRef,
  HostListener,
  Input,
  OnChanges,
} from '@angular/core';

/***
 * @example
 *  <div [scrollIntoForm] [index]="1">
 *  </div>
 */
@Directive({
  selector:
    // eslint-disable-next-line
    '[scrollIntoForm]',
})
export class ScrollIntoNewFormDirective implements OnChanges {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}
  @Input() public index: number;

  ngOnChanges(changes) {
    if (changes.index.currentValue != 0 && changes.index.firstChange) {
      this.el.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({
        block: 'center',
        inline: 'nearest',
        behavior: 'smooth',
      });
    }
  }

  @HostListener('click')
  onChangeOrder() {
    this.el.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({
      block: 'center',
      inline: 'nearest',
      behavior: 'smooth',
    });
  }
}
```

In component use:
`<div [formGroupName]="i" [scrollIntoForm] [index]="i"></div>`
In file component specs file: I declared ScrollIntoNewFormDirective. But when I run test, it show error:

`Template parse errors: Can't bind to 'scrollIntoForm' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. (""> <div [formGroupName]="i" [ERROR ->][scrollIntoForm] [index]="i"> <span class="label">連絡先: 優先度 {{ i + 1 }}</span> "): ng:///DynamicTestModule/CreatedAclFormComponent.html@249:35`

Please help me to fix it!!!

Comment: in file test, I imported directive file:
`declarations: [CreatedFwPolicyFormComponent, ScrollIntoNewFormDirective],`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.